# translateTo instead of just translate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am doing some positioning with translate during jQuery resize event and it would really come handy if translate weren't actually `translateBy`. It translates element by some amount. I've looked and haven't found the opposite functionality, `translateTo`.

Is there any tricks I can use to gain functionality similar to translate, but you specify the end position relative to container and not amount to translate?

Comment: what do you mean : `end specific position` . the `amount` is actually specifying the `end position` where the element to end up after the translate ( for example translateX(100px) specifies the element to end up 100px from the start point ` ). can you give an example ?

Comment: You’ll have to write yourself a little helper function, that calculates what values you need to translate _by_ to achieve the desired result.